# Connect Apple Airport Time Capsule via ethernet cable without disabling wi-fi internet connection on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, hard-drive, ethernet, lan

I would like to connect my Apple Airport Time Capsule to my Windows 7-based laptop via an ethernet cable without hindering my ability to connect to the internet wirelessly. I am currently using the Capsule as a harddrive, not a wireless hub. I receive wi-fi internet from another time capsule I already have set up.

The problem occurs when I am connected to the internet wirelessly and I connect my Capsule via ethernet cable. I immediately lose ability to use the internet, however, I am able to access my Capsule's harddrive at that point.

In short, I want to be able to access my Capsule's harddrive via the ethernet port and simultaneously be connected to the internet wirelessly.

My laptop: Toshiba Satellite P105-S6177

Thanks in advance for any tips, suggestions, and potential solutions!

-Rick.

Comment: @SuperRick - Be sure you request your accounts get merged.

Comment: This is a very odd heading to those of us that aren't overly familiar with Apple products.  No more flight delays with Apple Airport Time Capsule!

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind Network-Attached Storage (NAS) devices such as the Time Capsule is that you have a LAN (possibly a mixed LAN/WLAN), and the NAS device connects to that LAN, and you get to the NAS device through the LAN.

So the ideal solution here would be to wire your Time Capsule into the same LAN that the other Time Capsule is on, so that even when you cable up to the Time Capsule, you're still on the same LAN that has Internet connectivity, not some isolated stub LAN that only contains the backup-only Time Capsule.

[I suspect you have some reason you haven't stated for why you haven't already done this, like maybe it's too much time/hassle/expense to run Ethernet cabling between this Time Capsule and the rest of your LAN. But I'm going to post this Answer anyway because it may well be the right solution for a lot of other people who might find this Question.]